# netlogo - Randomly select a neighbour patch that has a higher elevation, any? command

Tags: patch, netlogo, turtle-graphics, elevation, hill-climbing

I've been tasked with a question of "randomly selecting a neighbour patch that has a higher elevation." My code is found below.

I believe I am required to use the "any?" command to prevent getting the 'nobody' issue.

```
to move-up
let myelevPatch [elevation] of patch-here
let higherpatches neighbors with [elevation > myelevPatch] 
move-to one-of higherpatches
end
```

I can't seem to get around this problem, if you could help me get around it, it is very much appreciated

Comment: You can replace `[elevation] of patch-here` with simply `elevation`. A turtle has direct access to the patch variables of the patch it is standing on.

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or incorrect behavior, or what? You've provided us with code, and say you have "this problem" with it. What is "this problem"? What is your evidence that your code is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be right other than the nobody case. Any? consumes a agentset. neighbors with returns an agentset.

```
to move-up
    let myelev [elevation] of patch-here
    let higherpatches neighbors with [elevation > myelev] 
    if any? higherpatches
    [move-to one-of higherpatches]
end
```

Note the following is equivalent:

```
if count higherpatches > 0
```

Comment: Note that I changed your variable name of myelevPatch to myelev since the type is not a patch.